XMLLINT split matches per line
Given xml
<parent>
   <child>test1</child>
   <child>test2</child>
</parent>

Using xmllint I can get the childs with:
| xmllint --format --xpath '//parent/child/text()' - 

This gives the result
test1test2
Is there an easy way to return it with a separator between them, e.g. test1-test2 or a space, like test1 test2.
The goal is to use the found matches in a pipeline and loop over them, but because everything is merged together without a separator it is not working.
EDIT using rhel7

If I redirect the output in a file, I get each text in a sep. row. Xmllint version 21206.

@Paul-ET Thanks for the suggestion, but i want terminal output, as pipelines, like jenkins, read console output. I do not want to use diskspace for getting command outputs.

I made the test on my Laptop (Win10), also on the Terminal it show up line by line. Maybe the Unix Version of xmllint work different.

xmllint --shell can be used as follows
printf "%s\n" 'cat //parent/child/text()' 'bye' | xmllint --shell <(cat tmp2.xml)
/ > cat //parent/child/text()
 -------
 test1 
 -------
 test2 
/ > bye

Cleaning the ouput
printf "%s\n" 'cat //parent/child/text()' 'bye' | xmllint --shell <(cat tmp2.xml) | grep -Ev '^(\/ > | ----)'
 test1 
 test2

